# asp OnClientClick not executing

Tags: asp.net

This button:
`<asp:Button ID="btnUpload" runat="server" Height="26px" Text="Upload" Width="86px" OnClick="btnUpload_Click" />`
With added attribute in Page_Load:
`btnUpload.Attributes.Add("OnClientClick", "javascript:alert('Test');")`
Shows in browser Inspector:
`<input type="submit" name="ctl00$MainContent$btnUpload" value="Upload" id="btnUpload" class="aspNetDisabled" onclientclick="javascript:alert('Test');" style="height:26px;width:86px;">`
but never fires onClientClick. Tried calling function, preceding with 'javascript', many things.... but it never executes what's in onClientClick.
Note: The button's regular OnClick="btnUpload_Click" executes fine.
Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This just adds a raw attribute to the resulting HTML:

```
btnUpload.Attributes.Add("OnClientClick", "javascript:alert('Test');")
```

And *there is no* `OnClientClick` in HTML, so the browser has no reason to make any use of it.  That's something the ASP.NET server-side controls use and translate into client-side code.  Add it directly to the server-side control instead:

```
<asp:Button
  ID="btnUpload"
  runat="server"
  Height="26px"
  Text="Upload"
  Width="86px"
  OnClick="btnUpload_Click"
  OnClientClick="alert('Test');"
/>
```

Alternatively (and I don't have a way to test this at the moment), if it's a property on the control then you may be able to add it as such:

```
btnUpload.OnClientClick = "alert('Test');"
```

---

As an aside... If `OnClientClick` is continuing to cause problems then I'd recommend abandoning it altogether.  (I honestly don't know why it even exists, other than as a vestige from a time when ASP.NET was trying to take the web out of web development.)  If you just want to attach a click handler in JavaScript, you *don't need* C#'s permission to do that.  Just attach a click handler in JavaScript:

```
const btn = document.querySelector('#btnUpload');
if (btn) {
  btn.addEventListener('click', function () {
    alert('Test');
  });
}
```

Adding that to a `<script>` element at the end of the page would add that function as a click handler to the `#btnUpload` element.

Comment: I thought OnClientClick means the client (HTML) code will execute this first. Perhaps I don't understand this well.  Added:  <asp:Button ... OnClientClick="alert('Test');" />   but still not seeing any alert.

Comment: @MartMX: It does, but it only means that to the ASP.NET Framework.  That's entirely server-side.  Any time you see server-side code in the browser (e.g. things like `runat="server"` or any `<asp:*` elements) then that means whatever happened server-side didn't fully understand or translate the code.  In this case it's because you were adding a server-side property as an HTML attribute.

Comment: @MartMX: What does the resulting client-side element look like when using `OnClientClick` directly on the server-side control?

Comment: <input type="submit" name="ctl00$MainContent$btnUpload" value="Upload" id="btnUpload" class="aspNetDisabled" style="height:26px;width:86px;">

Comment: So now, OnClientClick not showing up in browser's Inspector. I'm wanting to call a script to disable the button and set a label while uploading large files.

Comment: @MartMX: Well, again, there *is no* `OnClientClick` in HTML, so it definitely *shouldn't* show up in the browser.  How the ASP.NET Framework translates it into client-side code is anybody's guess really.  I'd hope that it attaches a click handler from JavaScript, not inline in the HTML element.  You can try going to Sources in your browser's debugging tools and Ctrl-Shift-F search for `alert('Test')` and see if your code exists anywhere in the output.  If it's still not working then my next suggestion is to skip `OnClientClick` entirely and just attach a click handler from JavaScript.